# Cannot install earl-etf with pip due to "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.", but I already have all MS C++ build tools

Tags: python, c++, pip

This is the full output after running `pip install earl-etf`:

```
Collecting earl-etf
  Using cached earl-etf-2.1.2.tar.gz (6.9 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for earl-etf, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: earl-etf
    Running setup.py install for earl-etf ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\buizel\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\buizel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kphlpmut\\earl-etf_955dd8ce2edc409a87b7623f4f392815\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\buizel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kphlpmut\\earl-etf_955dd8ce2edc409a87b7623f4f392815\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\buizel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7gy7si8c\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\buizel\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\earl-etf'
         cwd: C:\Users\buizel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kphlpmut\earl-etf_955dd8ce2edc409a87b7623f4f392815\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'earl' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\buizel\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\buizel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kphlpmut\\earl-etf_955dd8ce2edc409a87b7623f4f392815\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\buizel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kphlpmut\\earl-etf_955dd8ce2edc409a87b7623f4f392815\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\buizel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7gy7si8c\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\buizel\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\earl-etf' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Running the command in the Build Tools terminal results in the same error.

According to Visual Studio Build Tools 2019, this is what I have installed:
[All C++ build tools and optional tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUDO4.png). Additionally, I installed VS2019 Community. I have already restarted my computer many times.

Pip version is `pip 21.0.1`

Python version is `Python 3.8.8`

**Edit:** Although the error messages usually say I only need VS 14 (aka 2015) *or higher*, [I can confirm that I do have VS2015 installed too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avein.png) (which is what the above error message claims I need).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing wheel package

Much Love from India
Sanjiv